# MongoLab API Update: message: "Update object is missing."

Tags: mlab

Unable to update data in the data base. The above is a request link.

https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/my-db/collections/my-coll/52f7b875e4b0e615e67f0a41?jsonbody=[{"_id":"52f7b875e4b0e615e67f0a41","like":"true"}]&apiKey=my_api_key

Got. 400 Bad Request error and message: "Update object is missing."

Or anyone can give an example to update mongodb via REST API in java would be very helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the actual update spec, which should be the body of the `PUT` request. The [MongoLab Data API docs](http://docs.mongolab.com/restapi/#update-documents) include example of how to do that from jQuery, the key bits of which I've copied below for your convenience.

```
$.ajax( { url: 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/my-db/collections/my-coll?apiKey=myAPIKey&q={"_id":1234}',
          data: JSON.stringify( { "$set" : { "x" : 3 } } ),
          type: "PUT",
          contentType: "application/json" } );
```

Note that the `$set` update operator is not part of the `url`, but the body (which you specify in jQuery using the `data` field).

Comment: Thank Jared but I forgot to say that I am developing android app. I did set MethodRequest to PUT but it stills not work.

Comment: The error is telling you you're missing the body, which in the case of a PUT is the update object. If you can post the code you're using along with which HTTP library and version it's calling, perhaps I can show you how to add a body to the request. An HTTP body is not part of the URL. The `jsonbody` in your URL is just a URL parameter and will be ignored by the MongoLab API.